# Cannot figure out the factor of crashes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash, crash-reports

It's from Xcode organizer crash report. Crash happened when the app started, it seemed that `doesNotRecognizeSelector` caused the problem, but not like it used to be, the report did not point out the missing selector.

Can anyone guide how to figure out the problem from the limited information?

[image: crash report]

Comment: You have to provide more details with code. It seems that when you are posting some notification this issue is happening. Check the places where you are posting the Notification.

Comment: Your console or crash report also likely includes information about what selector was sent and to what class.

Comment: @Nandish @RobNapier  It's from user's crash report and that's all I have. The line `32 main` shows the problem in `AppDelegate`, but there is no any Notification `post`. Other lines do not refer to any other classes.

Comment: Then I think maybe, you have to integrate Google firebase crashlytics in your app to know the detailed crash log. line 32 main is a generic, it will be in all crash. You should look for proper place and that can be seen in crashlytics.